# SQL Server on Ubuntu error setup

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu

I want to install ms-sql to my Ubuntu 16.04:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-ubuntu

But when I try to set a password for the SA with the command **sudo /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr-setup** I got error:

**sqlservr: Debugger.cpp: 531: static void Debugger :: Print (const void *, unsigned int): Assertion `m_IsAttached 'failed.**

... and SA password is not set. How to solve a problem?

Comment: This question might be a better fit for [Stack DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).  If you agree you can move the question but clicking *flag* >> *should be closed..* >> *Off-topic because...* >> *Should be on another Stack site*.

Comment: Hello Vladislav, SQL Server PM here. Please email me to take a closer look at this at lbosq at microsoft dot com.